# Combine values from 3 arrays

Tags: arrays

I have 3 arrays

```
**var lastname = ['Smith','Jones'];
var firstname = ['John','Bob'];
var middlename = ['Fred','Tom'];**
```

How can I combine these into 1 array of 'Names' - with **2 values**

like  **'John Fred Smith' , Bob Tom Jones'**

How would you do this using **LO-DASH**

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is [zip function](https://lodash.com/docs#zip)

This will result in Array of arrays though, but they can be simply merged using standard `map` and `join` methods:

```
_.zip(firstname, middlename, lastname)
  .map(function(names){
    return names.join(" ")
  }
);

// -> [ 'John Fred Smith', 'Bob Tom Jones' ]
```